# Deleting the matching rows from the table

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

I am developing an application which has python ,flask frontend and sqlalchemy is connectivity layer.I have a table called Studentdepartment which has three columns combo_id,student_id,department_id.
Here one or more students can be in one department. For example

```
combo_id  student_id  department_id
1          1           1
2          2           1
3          3           1
4          4           2
```

combo_id is the primary key.
Now I have to delete the rows which has the department_id is 1.
I have tried this query

```
delete_updated_department_id = db.session.query(Studentdepartment).filter(Studentdepartment.department_id==department_id).delete()
hint:I am fetching the department id from my script.
```

But I am getting this error

```
 "Multiple rows were found for one()"
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.MultipleResultsFound: Multiple rows were found for one()
```

How should I delete all the rows which is matching with department id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I dont know why your code won't allow you to delete multiple rows, but if I remember correctly, the syntax below allows you delete multiple (all) rows that match the condition.

```
metadata = db.MetaData(bind=engine)
table_name = db.Table('Studentdepartment', metadata, autoload=True)
k = 'department_id'
v = department_id
query = table_name.delete()
query = query.where(getattr(table_name.c, k) == v)
my_session = Session(engine)
my_session.execute(query)
```

I'm using k, v here to easily expand the syntax with multiple conditions, but its not necessary here

Comment: Here department_id and student_id are foreign key of the table.is this the reason the rows are not getting deleted?

Comment: Does that mean you are still getting the same error when using my code snippet?